# while loop incriment causing different results based on where the increment expression in placed

Tags: java

Ok.. i made this wile loop in main---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int age=0;
    outer:
    while (age<21) {
        age++; 

        if(age==16){
            System.out.println("Get your licence");
            continue outer;
            }



          System.out.println("Another year");
        }
}
```

This produces the desired result--

***Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year
Get your licence
Another year
Another year
Another year
Another year Another year***

but if i shift the incrementer to the last line in the for loop.. something unexpected happens ..... **IT LEADS TO AN INFINITE LOOP**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int age=0;
    outer:
    while (age<21) {


        if(age==16){
            System.out.println("Get your licence");
            continue outer;
            }



          System.out.println("Another year");
          age++; 
        }


}
```

Results in...

*Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence
Get your licence.... till infinity*

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reach this point:

```
continue outer;
```

You return to the start of the loop, without incrementing  `age` and therefore you are going inside this condition (`age == 16`) over and over again.

Comment: that's ok.. but why do i never get the "Another Year" statement even once?

Comment: You do get it, but it's overriden fast enough by the infinite prints of "get your license"

Comment: @ Binyamin Sharlet- :( Did'nt show on the IDE output box even after scrolling to the top.... but i'll take your word...

Comment: Try putting a print before the while `outer:`, and see how fast it disappears :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're continuing before you increment, so you stay 16 forever *(hmmm, trying to decide whether that would be cool or hell...)*. There's nothing in a `while` loop that automatically increments the loop variable.

If you want a loop that always includes an increment, even when you `continue`, consider a `for` loop which would be a better choice for this situation in any case:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int age;

    for (age = 0; age < 21; ++age) {

        if(age==16){
            System.out.println("Get your licence");
            continue;
            }

          System.out.println("Another year");
        }
}
```

*(I hope I got your bracing style right there; it's quite alien to me...)*

...and separately, where possible it's best to avoid `continue` (although it definitely has good uses). In this case, a simple `else` would be a better choice:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int age;

    for (age = 0; age < 21; ++age) {

        if(age==16){
            System.out.println("Get your licence");
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Another year");
            }
        }
}
```

*(Again, apologies if I didn't quite get the bracing style right...)*

Comment: I get that.. but why do i never get the "Another Year" statement even once?

Comment: You do. Your code outputs it 16 times before the endless "Get a license" display. Just add another limiting variable to see it, like this: http://pastie.org/3620147 Note: It's **well worth** using a proper debugger to walk through your code in order to understand it.

Comment: @IamAPseudo-Intellectual: There are debuggers built into all of the major IDEs (Eclipse, Netbeans, JetBrains IDEA, ...). The only stand-alone debugger I've used with Java is [JSwat](http://code.google.com/p/jswat/) which, when I used it several years ago, was quite good indeed.